# Possible unintended reference comparison warning

Tags: c#, string

Code:

`if(Session["User_Name"]==String.Empty)`

It gives a warning:

> possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type string.

I try to fix the error:

```
if( Convert.ToString(Session["User_Name"])==String.Empty)
```

But I still get the warning. Please help me with this warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try simple cast:

```
if ((string)Session["User_Name"] == String.Empty) {...}
```

Better use string.IsNullOrEmpty:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["User_Name"])) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Response. I try the simple cast but i still get the same warning.

Comment: Thanks for your help . string.IsNullOrEmpty works!!!

Comment: @AatkaButt can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you the same error?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["User_Name"] as string))
```